# UWP - Theme based splash screen color

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, uwp-xaml

In my c# UWP app, I'd like to display a white splash screen for users with the light theme selected (in system settings) and back for users with the dark theme. However, in the `Package.appxmanifest`, `BackgroundColor` attribute does not support `ThemeResource`. It seems like it only accepts some predefined colors along with hex values. Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

> Theme based splash screen color

If you has not specified the app's splash background color in the capability. it will same as  Windows color where in the system setting. Splash color does not support pure black and white.For more detail please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/add-a-splash-screen).

Comment: Can you comment on how they achieve the functionality discussed in https://blogs.windows.com/windows-insider/2020/10/21/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-20241/?